# Pointers in C weird behavior inside a function

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

can someone explain this to me

```
main()
{
 int *x,y;
 *x = 1;
  y = *x;
 printf("%d",y);
}
```

when I compile it in gcc how come running this in main function is ok, while running it in different function wont work like the function below?

```
test()
{
 int *x,y;
 *x = 1;
  y = *x;
 printf("%d",y);
}
```

Comment: You are de-referencing a null pointer. Strangeness abound!

Comment: Not necessarily a null pointer; a pointer that has unknown garbage in it, which is worse.

Comment: yes i am dereferencing a null pointer but how come it would work in function main??

Comment: Because the value of the pointer is different and you are smashing, destroying, overwriting something else. It could also have crashed in main and not in the function. You're dereferencing a non initialized pointer, FWIW you could have flying monkeys fly out of your nose or started WW 3. That's 'undefined behaviour'.

Comment: yeah that is right dereferencing a null pointer but how come you have strange behavior, in main function it would work but in different function it wont?

Comment: @dj buen - You shouldn't be asking why it won't work in function main. You should be asking yourself, why am I trying to dereference a garbage pointer. Its really like shooting your arms off with a shotgun and then saying "Why doesn't my left arm bleed as much as my right arm is"

Comment: it could as well have crashed in your main and not in the func.  the only real answer is that you were lucky.

Answer (score 12):

```
int *x,y;
*x = 1;
```

[Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). `x` doesn't point to anything meaningful.

This will be correct:

```
int *x, y, z;
x = &z;
*x = 1;
y = *x;
```

or

```
int *x, y;
x = malloc(sizeof(int));
*x = 1;
y = *x;
//print
free(x);
```

Undefined behavior is, well, undefined. You can't know how it will behave. It can seem to work, crash, print unpredictable results and anything else. Or it can behave differently on different runs. Don't rely on undefined behavior

Comment: Undefined means it depends on what was on the stack before. And that depends on how the function is called.

Comment: Its also possible to write to a dereference expression (the C way of saying this: a dereference expression is an lvalue, meaning that it can appear on the left side of an assignment)

Comment: @Floste: Practically maybe you're right. Technically you aren't. @dj buen: I don't understand your point, I'm sorry. Can you rephrase?

Comment: i was just wondering about the implementation of compilers like gcc,turbo c etc..

Answer (score 3):

Technically, in standardese, you invoke what is called *undefined behavior* due to using an uninitialized value (the value of the pointer *x*).
What's going on under the hood is very likely this: your compiler allocates local variables on the stack. Calling functions likely changes the stack pointer, so different function's local variables are at different places on the stack. This in turn makes the value of the uninitialized x be whatever happens to be at that place in the current stack frame. This value can be different, depending on the depth of the chain of functions you called. The actual value can depend on a lot of things, e.g. back to the whole history of processes called before your program started. There's no point in speculating what the actual value might be and what kind of erroneous behavior might possibly ensue. In the C community we refer to undefined behaviour as even having the possibility to make [demons fly out of your nose](http://www.google.de/search?q=demons+fly+out+of+your+nose&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t). It might even start WW3 (assuming appropriate hardware is installed).

Seriously, a C programmer worth her money will take extreme care not to invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: No need to close a thread here (closing is more of an emergency procedure performed by _very_ reputable folks on bogus questions). There might be even better answers by future C gurus visiting this question.

Comment: @dj buen - Accept one of the answers, and that tells everyone else that you're satisfied with one of the solutions proposed.

Answer (score 2):

since x is a pointer, its not containing the int itself, it points to another memory location which holds that value.

***I think you assume that declaring a pointer to a value also reserves memory for it... not in C.***

If you made the above error in your code, maybe it would be good if I gave you a little bit more graphic representation of what is actually going on in the code... this is a common novice error.  The explanation below might seem a bit verbose and basic, but it might help your brain "see" what is actually going on.

Let's begin...  if `[xxxx]` is a value being stored in a few bits in the RAM, and [????] is an unknown value (in physical ram) you can say that that for X to be properly used it should be:

```
x == [xxxx]   ->   [xxxx]
x == address  of   a value (int)
```

when you write:  `*x=1` above, you are changing the value of an unknown area of RAM, so you are in fact doing:

```
x == [????]  -> [0001]    // address [????] is completely undefined !
```

In fact, we don't even know IF address [????] is allocated or accessible by your application (this is the undefined part), its possible the address points to **anything**.  Function code, dll address, file handle structure... it all depends on the compiler/OS/application state, and can **never** be relied on.

so to be able to use a pointer to an int, we must first **allocate** memory for it, and assign the address of that memory to x,  ex:

```
int y;   // allocate on the stack
x = &y;  // & operator means, *address* of"
```

or

```
x = malloc(sizeof(int));  // in 'heap' memory (often called dynamic memory allocation)

// here malloc() returns the *address* of a memory space which is at least large enough 
// to store an int, and is known to be reserved for your application.
```

at this point, we know that x holds a proper memory address so we'll just say it's currently set to `[3948]` (and contains an unknown value).

```
x == [3948]  ->  [????]
```

Using the `*` operator, you **dereference** the pointer address (i.e. look it up),  to store a value **AT** that address.

```
*x = 1;
```

means:

```
x == [3948]  ->  [0001]
```

I hope this helps